# Ruby on rails reverse before limiting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each, reverse

I have a list of articles where I use .reverse_each to show newest entries first. In an other page I would like to show the 3 newest, but I would like to reverse the list before sorting and I don't know how.

My code is:

```
<% @articles.take(3).reverse_each do |article| %>
   <a href="<%= article_path(article) %>"><h3 class="home-project-title"><%= article.title %></h3></a>
<% end %>
```

But this takes the 3 oldest entries and then reverses them? How can I reverse entries and then limit?

Comment: What is `@articles`? An array? AR relation?

Comment: For which field you want to do sorting ?

Comment: @articles is an array, yes

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, Vishal. I have my array, which is @articles, which consists of 20 entries, now I want to show the 3 latest entries. but my issues is that it lists the 3 oldest entries not te 3 newest.

Comment: Try using `@articles.order(id: :desc).limit(3).each do |article|`

Comment: Yes! it worked :) Can you explain what it does? I just started coding in Ruby.

Comment: I would not use id to order, instead use `@articles.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3)`

Answer (score 1):

**Just try:**

```
@articles.last(3).reverse_each
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@articles.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3)
```

Here is a breakdown of the different methods used:

- `order(created_at: :desc)`: tells ActiveRecord to add a clause `ORDER BY created_at DESC` to the SQL query
- `limit(3)`: tells ActiveRecord to add a clause `LIMIT 3` to the SQL query